# What is the interaction between "Touch of Death" and "Undead Fortitude"

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, class-feature, monk, zombies

The "Way of the Long Death" monk has a feature called "Touch of Death":

> ## Touch of Death
>
> Starting when you choose this tradition at 3rd level, your study of death allows you to extract vitality from another creature as it nears its demise. **When you reduce a creature within 5 feet of you to 0 hit points,** you gain temporary hit points equal to your Wisdom modifier + your monk level (minimum of 1 temporary hit point).

(Bold added for emphasis). How does this work when a WotLD Monk reduces a zombie to 0 hit points and the blow is shrugged off by undead fortitude?

> ## Undead Fortitude
>
> If damage reduces the zombie to 0 hit points, it must make a Constitution saving throw with a DC of 5+the damage taken, unless the damage is radiant or from a critical hit. On a success, the zombie **drops to 1 hit point instead.**

I could see this working one of two ways:

1. A zombie takes a hit, and *drops to 0 hit points*. Then Undead Fortitude kicks in and on a success, the zombie comes back to 1 HP. The zombie had been reduced to 0 hp, so ToD activates.
2. A zombie takes a hit, and makes a roll to see whether it drops to 0 or 1 HP. On a success, it drops to 1 HP and *had never dropped to 0*, therefore ToD does not activate.

Is there any official ruling on this case? If not, what is a reasonable interpretation of these rules?

Comment: Related: [Is there a general rule that covers interaction between effects that cause death?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/167807/is-there-a-general-rule-that-covers-interaction-between-effects-that-cause-death)

Comment: Related: [Can the half-orc's Relentless Endurance protect them from things that would normally kill someone instantly?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/165450/can-the-half-orcs-relentless-endurance-trait-protect-them-from-things-that-woul)

Answer (score 12):

#### I would rule that Touch of Death does not trigger if Undead Fortitude is triggered.

Touch of Death activates when:

> you reduce a creature within 5 feet of you to 0 hit points.

But Undead Fortitude says:

> the zombie drops to 1 hit point **instead**.

**Instead** here indicates that the zombie drops to 1 hit point instead of dropping to 0, so the trigger for Touch of Death never happens. Or to put it another way, the Zombie drops to 1 hitpoint instead of *[the trigger for Touch of Death]*, since "drops to 0 hit points" is the trigger for Touch of Death.

I would rule this way because Undead Fortitude appears to make it so that the trigger for Touch of Death never happened. There is room to rule otherwise though, as it still requires the DM to make an aparently arbitrary choice about the resolution order. Alternatively, we have some optional guidance...

#### An optional rule from *Xanathar's Guide* can change my ruling.

In *Xanathar's Guide*, we see an optional rule for resolving simultaneous effects:

> In rare cases, effects can happen at the same time, especially at the start or end of a creature’s turn. If two or more things happen at the same time on a character or monster’s turn, the person at the game table — whether player or DM — who controls that creature decides the order in which those things happen.

In this case, if it is the Monk's turn, they may choose to resolve Touch of Death before undead fortitude.

Comment: How can the zombie use its _Undead Fortitude_ if the triggering condition, being reduced to 0hp, is never met?

Comment: @Kirt I don't understand.

Comment: You say that the use of _Undead Fortitude_ means that the trigger for _Touch of Death_ never happens.  But the trigger for _Undead Fortitude_ is the zombie being reduced to 0hp.  I don't understand how you can argue that the zombie is never at 0hp when the ability that puts it at 1hp is not triggered unless and until it reaches 0 first.

Comment: @Kirt Becuase applying that logic to Undead Fortitude is the Liar’s Paradox.

Comment: The rules for _Undead Fortitude_, as written, do have an inherent contradiction similar to a Liar's Paradox.  If the zombie is at 0, it cannot 'drop' to 1.  We seem to agree that it is written poorly, but disagree about which aspect is wrong.  I think it is more likely, when describing a feature, that a writer would be sloppy about the word 'drop' than they would in describing the triggering condition for the feature itself.  YMMV.  Modifying 'drop' resolves the contradiction for me; apparently you would replace the trigger with 'if the zombie _would be reduced_ to 0hp'.

Comment: @Kirt It's the exact same rules interactions that allow a zombie, or a half-orc, to survive *disintegrate*. The special effect for that spell kicks in when the target is reduced to zero, but the survival abilities kick in first.

Comment: @Kirt There are multiple effects that retroactively prevent their triggers from taking place.  For example, the monk's Deflect Missile ability triggers when the monk is hit with a ranged weapon attack.  The monk can catch the missile, negating the hit.  The Hexblade's Armor of Hexes triggers when a cursed creature hits the warlock.  The warlock can potentially turn the hit into a miss.

Answer (score 1):

### Undead Fortitude and Touch of Death both trigger

Both Undead Fortitude and Touch of Death specify the circumstances under which they activate.

> When you reduce a creature within 5 feet of you to 0 hit points

and

> If damage reduces the zombie to 0 hit points

It is paradoxical to rule that Undead Fortitude prevents the Zombie from ever having been reduced to 0 hp because, if that were the case, then the feature would prevent its own trigger from occurring.

This can be compared to the Relentless feature of the [Wereboar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/wereboar) (MM, 209):

> if the wereboar takes 14 damage or less that would reduce it to 0 hit
> points, it is reduced to 1 hit point instead.

Since this triggers on the damage rather than on being reduced to 0 hp it would prevent Touch of Death from triggering.

Comment: In [this related answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/178647/does-undead-fortitude-work-if-you-have-only-1-hp/178651#178651) I compared _Undead Fortitude_ with _Relentless Endurance_.  I find your contrast of _Undead Fortitude_ with Wereboar _Relentless_ more informative, though, because of the change in tense.  "If damage _reduces_" means the Zombie **is** at 0, at least temporarily.  But "if damage _would reduce_" (conditional) means the Wereboar *is not* ever at 0.

Comment: @Kirt That argument ignores the crucial word "instead" in Undead Fortitude. There's no basis for the creature being at 0 hp "temporarily", as Undead Fortitude does not restore lost hit points.

Comment: @MarkWells  As Odo points out above, Undead fortitude does not trigger until the Zombie is at 0hp.  If the zombie is never at 0, it cannot use Undead Fortitude.  If it makes its save, it then is at 1hp **instead** of remaining at 0.

Comment: I think the crucial word from Undead Fortitude is actually "drops." If the Zombie is at 0 HP, it can't drop to 1.

Comment: @ScurvyShroom The rules for Undead Fortitude, as written, are self-contradictory. If the zombie is at 0, it cannot 'drop' to 1. We can agree on that, but disagree about which aspect of the feature is written wrong. I think it is more likely, when describing a feature, that a writer would be sloppy about the word 'drop' than they would in describing the triggering condition for the feature itself.  Furthermore, insisting on 'drop' as correct then means _UF_ also cannot work when the zombie is already at 1hp _before_ taking damage (and see the question I linked in the first comment).